# Odoo 9 Empty Tree View

Tags: python, xml, odoo, odoo-9

I have created a new model and added a tree view to edit/view it on the res.partner view.

I can create entries no problem and they appear in the database. I cannot however get the tree view to display any data at all. Even with the filters removed.

Here is the view xml

```
<page string="Projects/Training">
    <field name="training_logs" context="{'default_tl_partner_id': active_id}" domain="[('tl_partner_id','=',active_id)]">
        <tree string="Training Logs" editable="top">
            <field name="tl_partner_id" invisible="1"/>
            <field name="tl_date"/>
            <field name="tl_trainer"/>
            <field name="tl_present"/>
            <field name="tl_summary"/>
        </tree>
    </field>
</page>
```

Model Structure as requested

```
class training_log(osv.Model):
_name='training.log'
_description='Log of past training events'
_order='tl_date'
_columns = {
    'tl_partner_id': fields.many2one('res.partner', 'Customer'),
    'tl_date': fields.date("Training Date"),
    'tl_trainer': fields.many2one('res.users', 'Trainer'),
    'tl_present': fields.char('People Present'),
    'tl_summary': fields.text('Training Summary')
}
```

res.partner - I have left out all my non related fields.

```
class res_partner(osv.osv):
_inherit = "res.partner"
_columns = {

    'training_logs': fields.one2many('training.log','id','Training Logs'),



}
```

Comment: Please update your question with model structure.

Comment: where is model structure for *res.partner* object ?

Comment: As I mentioned above I already tried it with the filters off. I tried taking domain and context out again but the tree is still blank.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When we define *one2many* field, we need to give proper *many2one* field name.

In your case, you have given *id* which means it will take currently record not for as you have created new object *training.log*

Try with following code:

Replace

```
'training_logs': fields.one2many('training.log','id','Training Logs'),
```

with

```
'training_logs': fields.one2many('training.log','tl_partner_id','Training Logs'),
```

Afterwards, restart Odoo server and upgrade module.

Comment: Thanks very much for your help.